# Intermediate Integration Question

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I'm having difficulty understanding why

$$\int \left[ \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) ^2 + \left( y \right) \left( \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} \right) \right]dx = \left( y \right) \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)$$

Comment: Take the derivative of the RHS

Comment: Use integration by parts on the square of the first derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=f(x)$

Consider $\int (f'(x)^2)$ d$x$. $\int (f'(x))^2$ d$x= f'(x)f(x)- \int f''(x)f(x)$ d$x$.

I.e. $\int (\frac{dy}{dx})^2$ d$x= y\frac{dy}{dx}-\int y \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ d$x$.

This nicely cancels out with the term $\int y (\frac{d^2y}{dx^2})$ d$x$, and yields the required integral by simple addition.